# Identify Week Number, Month Number, Year from DatePicker control in VBA userform

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker, textbox

I have been trying to make my user form work by getting codes everywhere. I don't have any experience in VBA so the code that I have are patches from different sources.

I have a datepicker control in my user form and i'd like to get the corresponding week number, month number and year based on the date that is chosen from the datepicker control box and populate the corresponding textboxes for each

[datepicker and textbox dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIRv5.png).

Comment: Could you show us your attempt? Some code?

Comment: Thanks Werenerson...I've deleted my attempts thus far...but i was trying to modify the following code which i found online to no availa...i guess it was wrong..Sub textboxes()
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .TextBox2 = WeekNum(.TextBox1)
End With
End Sub

Function WeekNum(D As Date) As Integer
     WeekNum = CInt(Format(D, "ww", 2))
End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the week number use the below. The third and fourth arguments allow you to dictate the first day/first week of the year.

```
TextBoxWeek.Value =  DatePart("ww", TextBoxDatePicker.Value, vbMonday, vbFirstJan1 )
```

Month:

```
TextBoxMonth.Value = format(TextBoxDatePicker.value,"mm")
```

Year: (you can also use "yy" to get the shorthand date eg. '17' rather than '2017')

```
TextBoxYear.Value = format(TextBoxDatePicker.value, "yyyy")
```

Comment: thank you jmdon...should this be added under the following part of my code? Private Sub DTPicker3_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)

End Sub

Comment: Is your date picker a combo box, it should go in the Change event of your date picker inside your UserForm module, eg: Private Sub ComboBox1_Change() End Sub

Comment: hi jmdon...so this worked great when my date completed field has a value but for entries where this should be left blank the datepicker seems impractical so i've resorted to using a textbox instead so that the coordinators can manually update the field...now the problem is the functions you provided no longer work..i've tried using cdate to convert the text but i keep getting an error :( my attempt is below:

Comment: Private Sub DateCompleted_Change()
Dim dDT As Date
dDT = CDate(Me.DateCompleted.Value)
TextBox1.Value = dDT

WeekNumTxt.Value = DatePart("ww", TextBox1.Value, vbMonday, vbFirstJan1)
MonthNumTxt.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "mm")
YearTxt.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "yyyy")
End Sub
When i run the macro it says run-tim error: 13 type mismatch...can you enlighten me further? thanks so much!

Comment: It is likely that if DateCompleted is changed but the value is blank, the rest of the code won't work as it can't convert a blank string to a date. You can try surrounding the code so it will only attempt to convert the dates if the date picker has a value. with an IF statement, eg: If DateCompleted.Value <> "" Then. In the Else you can set your textbox values to blank if required, so if the date picker is blank the rest of the text boxes will update to blank.

Comment: Thnka jmdon...im still trying to learn vba so I'm not entirely sure how to do this...i have instead created a workaround by adding an invisible textbox which then takes the value of the datepicker when it is changed...thank you so much for your help!